# htaccess redirects files inside folder but not the root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Using .htaccess, I want to redirect all requests to a deleted directory to the root of another directory:

1. `mywebsite.com/deleted-directory/anyfile` → `mywebsite.com/new-directory/`
2. `mywebsite.com/deleted-directory` → `mywebsite.com/new-directory/`
3. `mywebsite.com/deleted-directory/` → `mywebsite.com/new-directory/`

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^deleted-directory(/.*)?$ /new-directory/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

Problem:

1. works
2. works
3. **does not** (error 404, no redirection)

---

Notes:

- the folder `deleted-directory` has already been deleted, I cannot put the .htaccess file inside, the .htaccess is in the parent folder (root of the server)
- I used `R=302` for testing only (no caching)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteRule ^old-directory(/.*)?$ /new-directory/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: This solution works better but not all the way through: now `mywebsite.com/old-directory` gets well redirected to `mywebsite.com/new-directory/`, but `mywebsite.com/old-directory/` (with the closing slash) still throws a 404 error (updated my question accordingly).